# DataBinder Wraps HTML in Quotes

Tags: html, asp.net, data-binding

I am using a Rich Text Editor and saving the data into a SQL database and then pulling the data using a Databinder and displaying the value within a div. The issue is that the html code is wrapped in quotes making it now show up for some reason.

This is what my code looks like to pull the value from the database:

```
<div class="blog_text">
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Content").ToString()%>
</div>
```

Here is what the database value looks like:

```
&amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;color: #000000; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px; background: #efefef;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Pacific Power Group is proud to have employees who share our values and decication join our team and help ensure that we provide the best service at all of our divisions. Please help us welcome the latest employees who joined Pacific in February:&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;br style=&amp;quot;color: #000000; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: #efefef;&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;div style=&amp;quot;color: #000000; background: #efefef;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;table border=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot; cellspacing=&amp;quot;3&amp;quot; cellpadding=&amp;quot;3&amp;quot; style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;tbody style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left; width: 172px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Medford&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt; Justin Daniels&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Apprentice Chassis Technician&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Portland&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt; Jordan Kryla&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Golf Car Technician&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt; Michelle Steele&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Sales Admin I&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Kent&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt; Edward Miller&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Drafter&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt; Kyle Huston&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Parts Front Counter&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Spokane&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt; Jeffrey Clark&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Apprentice Engine Technician&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Perkins&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt; Gerardo Ponce&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Production Specialist I&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Corporate&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;tr style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt; Shauna Olsen&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;td style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Assistant Controller&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
        &amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;/tbody&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;/table&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="blog_text">
 "       
                        <p style="color: #000000; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px; background: #efefef;">Pacific Power Group is proud to have employees who share our values and decication join our team and help ensure that we provide the best service at all of our divisions. Please help us welcome the latest employees who joined Pacific in February:</p>
<br style="color: #000000; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: #efefef;" />
<div style="color: #000000; background: #efefef;">
<table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left; width: 172px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"><strong>Medford</strong></td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"> Justin Daniels</td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;">Apprentice Chassis Technician</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"><strong>Portland</strong></td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"> Jordan Kryla</td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;">Golf Car Technician</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"> Michelle Steele</td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;">Sales Admin I</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"><strong>Kent</strong></td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"> Edward Miller</td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;">Drafter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"> Kyle Huston</td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;">Parts Front Counter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"><strong>Spokane</strong></td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"> Jeffrey Clark</td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;">Apprentice Engine Technician</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"><strong>Perkins</strong></td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"> Gerardo Ponce</td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;">Production Specialist I</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"><strong>Corporate</strong></td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;"> Shauna Olsen</td>
            <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left;">Assistant Controller</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</div>          "
```

Notice the quote at the beginning and the end of the result HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just trim the data string? Like this:

C#

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Content").ToString().Trim('\"')%>
```

VB

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Content").ToString().Trim(CChar(""""))%>
```